# How to exclude the particular folder in gcs bucket in google cloud while copying to local machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to copy the files and folders from google cloud storage to vm machine using gsutil command but i need to exclude few of the folders in the gcs bucket while copying to vm, i tried searching for the options but i couldn't find it, please help if anyone knows the command for this.

Thanks in-advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use a command like:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r -x '^dir3/*' gs://bucket
```

this should retrieve all objects located on the bucket, except objects beginning with dir3 (files not located in dir3 directory in your example).

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) you can find more details about the rsync command